# Unable to convert to double for cost number

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I cant seem to get my cost value to show decimal places. The code below for value "100.00" only gives me "100" When I debug the value of Session("TotalProductCost") is 100D?

```
Session("TotalProductCost") = Convert.ToDecimal(Cost1) + Convert.ToDecimal(Cost2) + Convert.ToDecimal(Cost3) + Convert.ToDecimal(Cost4) + Convert.ToDecimal(Cost5)


Dim TotalProductAmt As Decimal
Decimal.TryParse(Session("TotalProductCost"), TotalProductAmt)
Dim Res As Decimal =  TotalProductAmt
TotalAmount = TotalProductAmt.ToString()
TotalAmount = Res.ToString
```

Comment: Try adding a format string like this TotalAmount = TotalProductAmt.ToString("n2")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the result of ToString to always include two decimal places, you need to tell ToString that. You can pass a string parameter which tells ToString what kind of result you expect, like this:

```
TotalAmount = Res.ToString("F2")
```

The above tells ToString "I want the result to be fixed to two decimal places". If you hand it the value 1000, the string you get back will be "1000.00".

Alternatively, if you also want the digits to be grouped such that 1000 results in "1,000.00" (or some other grouping system, depending on which country you're in), you can pass in "N2" as your parameter to ToString:

```
TotalAmount = Res.ToString("N2")
```

For details of this and other string formats you can pass to ToString, see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

As for why Visual Studio is showing you "100D", the D signifies that you're looking at a decimal value (as opposed to an integer or whatever).

Comment: Whats the difference between ("F2") and ("N2")?

Comment: I've just edited my answer to include N2 as well, after spotting that somebody else had mentioned N2. Basically, F2 will only fix how many decimal places you want, while N2 will also group the digits so that 1000000 will come out as "1,000,000.00" (or something appropriate to the country you're in) rather than just the "1000000.00" that F2 will give you.

Comment: Thank you I never knew this